# How to prevent select2.js from overriding custom changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am experimenting with [select2](https://select2.github.io/options.html#adapters) by adding custom tags to it.

I do this with this code:

```
        $(".js-example-basic-multiple")
            .on("select2:selecting",
                function() {
                    e.params.args.data.text = parentTarget + e.params.args.data.text;
                });
```

I am using the multiple attribute BUT i am using the optgroup elemnt of the select list and it acts as a parentId container where only one element per container can be selected. This is solved but what i can not do is remove "MycustomTag" from previous selected option.

MycustomTag is either

> Users

Or

> Tank

And when selecting a new option i want to remove the Tank/Users tag on the previous selected option. In my debuging process i found that this is getting overriden in the change event but I can't figure out how to stopp it.

the code is pretty huge so I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/11ot4cf6/8/)

How can I remove the tag that I am setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some extensive detective work I found a very simple answer...

```
 $(this).data().data.text = $(this).data().data.text.replace(parentTarget, "");
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/11ot4cf6/9/) has been updated